# Trouble with Spying on Mock for NavController in Jasmine tests on Ionic2 (Angular2) project

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, mocking, ionic2

I've created an Ionic2 project based on [Josh Morony's TDD tutorial](https://www.joshmorony.com/test-driven-development-in-ionic-2-navigation-and-spies/).  I'm using a left-side menu (defined in the app module), so I'm trying to write tests on the links in the menu.

Unfortunately, I'm getting an error that I can't figure out.  It seems to be related to the NavController, so maybe I need to change the way I'm mocking it. Should I use `mockNavController` [from the Ionic library](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/src/util/mock-providers.ts)? `mockNavController` from `../../node_modules/ionic-angular/util/mock-providers` didn't seem to help...

The error is triggered by `fixture.detectChanges()`.  I've removed some of my code in the blocks below, but I think I included everything relevant to the error.

**app.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By }           from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicModule, Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NavMock, StatusBarMock, SplashScreenMock } from '../mocks';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { PlatformMock } from '../../test-config/mocks-ionic';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';

describe('MyApp Component', () => {
  let fixture;
  let component;
  let de: DebugElement;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        MyApp,
        HomePage
      ],
      imports: [
        IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: NavController, useClass: NavMock },
        { provide: StatusBar, useClass: StatusBarMock },
        { provide: SplashScreen, useClass: SplashScreenMock },
        { provide: Platform, useClass: PlatformMock },
        OverlayService
      ]
    })
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyApp);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  it ('should be created', () => {
    expect(component instanceof MyApp).toBe(true);
  });

  it('displays the home page to the user', () => {
    expect(component['rootPage']).toBe(HomePage);
  });

  it('links to the pages in the menu', () => {
    let navCtrl = fixture.debugElement.injector.get(NavController);
    spyOn(navCtrl, 'setRoot');

    fixture.detectChanges();
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#menu-content ion-list button'));

    de[0].triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(navCtrl.setRoot).toHaveBeenCalledWith(HomePage, {});
  });

});
```

**mocks.ts**

```
export class NavMock {

  public pop(): any {
    return new Promise(function(resolve: Function): void {
      resolve();
    });
  }

  public push(): any {
    return new Promise(function(resolve: Function): void {
      resolve();
    });
  }

  public getActive(): any {
    return {
      'instance': {
        'model': 'something',
      },
    };
  }

  public setRoot(): any {
    return true;
  }

  // ADDED TO PUSH FORWARD THIS TEST PAST A PREVIOUS ERROR
  public registerChildNav(): any {
    return true;
  }

  // ADDED TO TRY AND FIX THIS ERROR
  public _config: any = {
    plt: {
      isRTL: function() {return true;}
    }
  }
}

export class PlatformMock {
  public ready(): any {
    return new Promise((resolve: Function) => {
      resolve();
    });
  }
}

export class StatusBarMock {
  public styleDefault(): any {
    return true;
  }
}

export class SplashScreenMock {
  public hide(): any {
    return true;
  }
}
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Nav, Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';


@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html',
  entryComponents: [
    HomePage
  ]
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  rootPage: any = HomePage;

  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;

  constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    this.initializeApp();

    // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Home', component: HomePage }
    ];

  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  openPage(page) {
    // Reset the content nav to have just this page
    // we wouldn't want the back button to show in this scenario
    this.nav.setRoot(page.component);
  }
}
```

**app.html**

```
<ion-menu [content]="content">
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar color="dark">
      <ion-title>MyApp</ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-content id="menu-content">
    <ion-list>
      <button menuClose ion-item *ngFor="let p of pages" (click)="openPage(p)">
        {{p.title}}
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-content>

</ion-menu>

<ion-nav [root]="rootPage" #content swipeBackEnabled="false"></ion-nav>
```

---

**The error shown in the testing console:**

```
Error: Error in ./MyApp class MyApp - inline template:17:0 caused by: this._config.plt.isRTL is not a function
TypeError: this._config.plt.isRTL is not a function
 at NavControllerBase._transitionInit (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:633:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:46642:37)
 at NavControllerBase._postViewInit (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:511:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:46520:14)
 at NavControllerBase._viewTest (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:607:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:46616:25)
 at NavControllerBase._nextTrns (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:350:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:46359:25)
 at NavControllerBase._queueTrns (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:300:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:46309:14)
 at NavControllerBase.push (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/navigation/nav-controller-base.js:73:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:46082:21)
 at Nav.ngAfterViewInit (webpack:///~/ionic-angular/components/nav/nav.js:116:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:64546:18)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MyApp0.detectChangesInternal (/DynamicTestModule/MyApp/component.ngfactory.js:298:63)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:119333:14)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:119528:44)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:410:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:119318:18)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_MyApp_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/DynamicTestModule/MyApp/host.ngfactory.js:35:19)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:425:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:119333:14)
 at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view.js:620:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:119528:44)
 at ViewRef_.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/linker/view_ref.js:170:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:80579:20)
 at ComponentFixture._tick (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:196:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:17119:36)
 at webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:210:45 <- karma-test-shim.js:17133:53
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106054:26)
 at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105721:39)
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:228:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106053:32)
 at Object.onInvoke (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:273:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:39578:37)
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:228:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106053:32)
 at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105938:43)
 at NgZone.run (webpack:///~/@angular/core/src/zone/ng_zone.js:142:42 <- karma-test-shim.js:39447:62)
 at ComponentFixture.detectChanges (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:210:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:17133:29)
 at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///src/app/app.component.spec.ts:62:14 <- karma-test-shim.js:135767:17)
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106054:26)
 at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:79:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105721:39)
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:228:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106053:32)
 at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105938:43)
 at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js:102:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105436:34)
 at webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:96:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:17019:21
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:229:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106054:26)
 at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105026:39)
 at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105718:39)
 at ZoneDelegate.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:228:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106053:32)
 at Zone.run (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:113:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105938:43)
 at AsyncTestZoneSpec._finishCallback (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:91:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:17014:29)
 at webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:38:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105015:31
 at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:262:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106087:35)
 at Zone.runTask (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:151:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:105976:47)
 at ZoneTask.invoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:332:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106157:33)
 at data.args.(anonymous function) (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1149:0 <- karma-test-shim.js:106974:25)
```

Comment: The app itself is working.  Only the unit tests have any problems (likely restricted to the mocking).